# How to get input from user for timer

Tags: android, input, time, timer

I want to get user input of minutes/seconds for a timer

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { }
```

The 30000 (30 second) value I want that from a user

```
t= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
```

The value is stored in t

How do I achieve this?

```
new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) { }
```

This wont work...

Comment: Before posting a question, try researching possible answers to what can be going wrong with your text collection from the edit text, there is an answer on stackoverflow MOST LIKELY.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the text from EditText from android convert it to long milliseconds.

```
t= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);
long userinput = Long.parseLong(t.getText().toString());
new CountDownTimer(userinput, 1000) { } ;
```

Though you have to do some input validation checking else you might get exception later on.

Answer (score 1):

> new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) { }

Here your **t** variable is `EditText` - its object and first parameter of CountDownTimer expects **long** so you need to get content of EditText and then parse it to long:

```
Long.parseLong(t.getText().toString());
```

**Note:** Also good practise is to validate input of User (input is not always correct you need to assume that User is "stupid" and can add some bullshit) if its correct number that can be parsed into long:

```
String input = t.getText().toString();
if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
   // its valid number
   Long.parseLong(t.getText().toString());
}
```

Or you can ensure it via `XML` when you'll specify *inputType* for EditText:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

`t` is `EditText` if you want get value in `Long` you must use:

```
    Long.parseLong(t.getText().toString())
```

if you want any type else you must cast from `t.getText.toString()`